# cyclic permutation or numpy.roll() type function to dplyr group

Tags: r, dplyr

If I have data like:

```
g in
1 a
1 b
1 c
1 d
2 e
2 f
2 g
2 h
```

with g being the group How can I use dplyr to create a second column with the values like:

```
g in out
1 a  b
1 b  c
1 c  d
1 d  a
2 e  f
2 f  g
2 g  h
2 h  e
```

That is a roll() or permutation which takes the first row and puts it at the end. I have tried combinations of lead/lag, vector slices inside c(), tail/head using  the standard evaluation functions.  I either get no such desired permutation, NAs (which I don't want), or a type conversion from factor to int.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `lead` with `default` as the `first` value of "In"

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
    group_by(g) %>% 
    mutate(Out=dplyr::lead(In, default=first(In)))
#       g    In   Out
#  (int) (chr) (chr)
#1     1     a     b
#2     1     b     c
#3     1     c     d
#4     1     d     a
#5     2     e     f
#6     2     f     g
#7     2     g     h
#8     2     h     e
```

NOTE: I changed the column name from "in" to "In" as it could create some trouble while calling within `mutate`.

Comment: wow thanks!  I was not using the dplyr:: version, and didnt know about the default argument.